# Why is it called get_template_directory and get_stylesheet_directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

Im new to Wordpress and i have subthemed Nisarg by making my child theme caribia. Now inside of my themes functions.php i want to add a few styles and a few scripts, so i have the following code(that works fine):

```
function caribia_enqueue_scripts() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    wp_enqueue_style($parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script('caribia', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/caribia.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'caribia_enqueue_scripts' );
```

so its fine that its called wp_enqueue_scripts, but that should only be used for the scripts right? why isn't there a function called wp_enqueue_styles?

Another question i have is, why does the function get_template_directory()  return the URL for my parent theme? and get_stylesheet_directory() return my current theme directory, i would imagine get_stylesheet_directory() should return my_theme/styles  or my_theme/css  .

Thanks

Comment: There is a function called `wp_enqueue_style`

Comment: Yeah  i know. im using both the wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script in the code right above. but the add_action($tag, ...) method only has the tag 'wp_enqueue_scripts' instead of also having a method called 'wp_enqueue_styles' ... which is what it is, but i definitely dont understand my second question about the stylesheet directory and the template directory.

Comment: get_stylesheet_directory() is a custom function in wp. It is designed for use with parent themes where the author supports child themes, so if a child theme is installed, the function will return the directory of the child theme. One use is in enqueuing the css file but its used for other things also. Where a file/path is strictly in the parent theme only, you can use template_directory to return this.